# Spam email addresses hiding in iPhone calendar sharing

Tags: iphone, icloud, email, calendar, ical

I got some spam events in my Apple iCloud calendar events and have been able to delete them by deleting the calendars. However, when I make a new calendar, I am finding it's being shared with two Chinese fake emails. It only shows in the iPhone calendar app.

In the App, I click Calendars at the bottom to show them all - in the iCloud if I press the ***i*** button at the right side of the relevant calender, it says "shared with/add person" - when I click this it has my own iCloud email address and two Chinese spam email addresses. These two reappear with every iPhone iCloud calendar I make and I can't delete them. clicking on them just brings up a "new email" to that email address.

I cant find anything on Google about this, just how to block/remove events. How do I get rid of these spam email addresses sharing my iCloud iPhone calendars?

This is not about how to remove the events but finding that my calendar has been shared with two spam email addresses (probably appeared since the event hacking) that I now cannot remove.  I'd do a screen shot if I could share it.

Comment: In which specific App are you trying to do this? That is, within your iPhone Calendar app, your macOS Calendar app, in the iCal app on older versions of Mac OS X, via a web browser logged into your iCloud? Basically these email addresses are only appearing as options because the system is remembering that they've been used in the past for calendar sharing. While harmless, the process to get rid of them may depend on exactly where you're seeing them.

Comment: I have the same thing!  (except that I am on OSX)  could this be an apple wide hack?

Comment: I just posted my own question:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262470/how-to-prevent-these-alerts-from-appearing-on-my-calendar

Comment: It is in my iPhone 5s, in the calendar app, telling me who the calendar has been shared with. It's not visible in the macAir. And it's not a duplicate question, thanks for understanding monomeeth, it's not about the actual getting of events but the trail behind it. I'm hopeful these shared addresses aren't going to have access to anything. There is no option to remove them..

Comment: Please add a screenshot then.

Comment: Rosie - the [help] page shows how to edit the post and upload an image. You could also post it elsewhere publicly on the web and hope someone here can help edit it. It's not clear how this is different from the linked question to me yet.