# how to prevent these alerts from appearing on my calendar

Tags: icloud, mail.app, calendar, malware, hacking

My email address was sold a while ago so I get a lot of junk mail.  I try to delete it and unsubscribe but some of it remains.  Recently, messages such as the image below have started appearing on my calendar.  Does this mean that I have a virus or that someone is accessing my iCloud account?  A while ago my email name changed without my knowledge leading to some interesting times!  is this related possibly?

Does anyone have suggestions on what this is, how to fix it, or how to prevent this in the future?

[image]
[image]